# scoped_model Snackbar running before state is initialized?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code:

```
ScopedModelDescendant<SignInInfo>(
                      builder: (context, child, model) => snackBarBuilder(model.errorMessage, context),
                    ),
```

```
Widget snackBarBuilder(String errorMessage, BuildContext context) {
  if (true) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage, style: GoogleFonts.lato(),)));
  } else {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Ignoring the always true boolean as a placeholder, how can I show a snackbar using the Scoped Model package? The error I get is `Null check operator used on a null value`. It happens because it happens before the build.

If I use:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage, style: GoogleFonts.lato(),)));
    });
```

It works. Is there any other way? I want to show multiple snackbars so that one isn't an ideal soution.

Answer (score 0):

I had placed the `ScopedModelDescendent` as a child of a Column, so that's why I have an error. I placed this in a button press and now it works fine... Took me this long.